# Adjacent JSX elements must be wrapped in an enclosing tag (React-Native)

Tags: react-native, reactjs, jsx

How can I solve that, because i can't figure out how to solve. I change the some parts of the code, change the root and add some codes on root,js to try not crash the entire app, but still show me this error. thanks for the help.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, TouchableOpacity, View } from 'react-native';

export default class Tabs extends Component {

  state = {
    activeTab: 0
  }

  render({children} = this.props) {
    return (
     <div> 
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.tabsContainer}>
          {children.map(({ props: { title } }, index) => {
            <TouchableOpacity
              style={[
                // Default style for every tab
                styles.tabContainer,
                index === this.state.activeTab ? styles.tabContainerActive : []
              ]}
              // Change active tab
              onPress={() => this.setState({ activeTab: index }) }
              // Required key prop for components generated returned by map iterator
              key={index}
            >
              <Text style={styles.tabText}>
                {title}
              </Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        <View style={styles.contentContainer}>
          {children[this.state.activeTab]}
        </View>
      </View>
     </div> 
    );
  }
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,                           
  },
  tabsContainer: {
    flexDirection: 'row',               
    paddingTop: 30,                     
  },
  tabContainer: {
    flex: 1,                           
    paddingVertical: 15,              
    borderBottomWidth: 3,             
    borderBottomColor: 'transparent',
  },
  tabContainerActive: {
    borderBottomColor: '#FFFFFF',       
  },
  tabText: {
    color: '#FFFFFF',
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
  contentContainer: {
    flex: 1                             
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a closing view tag for the tabs container and you can remove the div:

```
render({children} = this.props) {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.tabsContainer}>
          {children.map(({ props: { title } }, index) => 
            <TouchableOpacity
              style={[
                // Default style for every tab
                styles.tabContainer,
                index === this.state.activeTab ? styles.tabContainerActive : []
              ]}
              // Change active tab
              onPress={() => this.setState({ activeTab: index }) }
              // Required key prop for components generated returned by map iterator
              key={index}
            >
              <Text style={styles.tabText}>
                {title}
              </Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
         }
        </View>
        <View style={styles.contentContainer}>
          {children[this.state.activeTab]}
        </View>
      </View>
    );
};
```

Comment: Hi, I have changed but doesn't work and show the same error on (32:8)

Comment: I have updated the answer I just copied the question code, and didn't noticed that the children.map was not being closed (In the question you close the map after the parens)

Comment: note that you need to remove line 37 from your original questions since that bracket is extra

Comment: I have changed, now I think is working. Except, started for the a unexpected token in:                                                                                             const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,                           
  },                                                                                                                       By he way, thanks @valarauko

Comment: Cool, if the my answer helped please accept it as best answer to prevent this question to appear in the unanswered question list.